# Download file passing headers using the Cordova file transfer plugin is given error code 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to download a file using cordova file transfer plugin. I am passing authentication header value  the plugin and using that I am trying to download the file. It returns error code 1 (connection error). But without headers I can download normal file successfully by using this plugin. My codes' structure is shown in below. Please help me to resolve this issue.

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function(){

```
    var url = "http://www.gajotres.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png";
    token = "Bearer" + authtoken
    var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    options = {};
    trusHost = true;

    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trusHost).then(function (result) {
        console.log('Success');
}, function (error) {
        console.log('Error code' + error.code);
}, function (progress) {
        // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
},false,{

    "Authorization" = token

});
```

});

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this? It seems I have the same problem... Thanks!